# how can i fix the problem with cdk module

Tags: angular, angularjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPQ7H.png)
this error keeps poping everytime i resize the window

i was expecting once i reduce the page size the search bar becomes an icon that has a fall down search bar so i tried to change things with the html and the css but the error keeps popping so i concluded that the error is from this line

```
<button [cdkMenuTriggerFor]="searchOverlay" class="search-menu-btn ripple">
```

which leads to this code

```
<ng-template #searchOverlay>
    <div class="overlay overlay-search overlay-fall" cdkMenu>
        <input type="search" class="search" name="" id="" placeholder="Search...">
        <button class="search-btn">
            <i class="far fa-search search-icon"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Can you add the code around "firstCreatePass"?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function providersResolver(def, providers, viewProviders) {
const tView = getTView();
if (tView.firstCreatePass) {
    const isComponent = isComponentDef(def);
    // The list of view providers is processed first, and the flags are updated
    resolveProvider(viewProviders, tView.data, tView.blueprint, isComponent, true);
    // Then, the list of providers is processed, and the flags are updated
    resolveProvider(providers, tView.data, tView.blueprint, isComponent, false);
}
```

}

Comment: i do not think the problrm is there because everytime i delete `[cdkMenuTriggerFor]="searchOverlay" ` the logo appears